# What can a felon do to improve his chances of getting a job?

Tags: interviewing, resume

In general, what are some suggestions that a felon should follow in order to find work. In regards to resume, communication, disclosure, and so forth. My specific situation is that I'm a statistician with four years of experience and a masters degree from a good university. Recently lost my job and am finding it very difficult, but I also have a slightly more serious felony (felony sex offense that resulted in three years of probation).

Comment: Where are you from? Crimes are culturally and legally context specific. What can be a felony in one place might not even be a crime in another

Comment: Possible duplicates:  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50365/when-should-i-tell-a-prospective-employer-about-a-criminal-conviction-that-resul  http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/48494/convicted-felon-looking-for-a-job

Comment: @JimG. No we don't need to know the felony.  But where does matter.